# mongosh: how to connect with uuidRepresentation=javaLegacy?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I am connecting to my local host mongodb via moongo shell with the following command and getting the following error.

Command

```
mongosh  "mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/authDb?uuidRepresentation=javaLegacy"
```

Error

```
Connecting to:          mongodb://<credentials>@localhost:27017/authDb?uuidRepresentation=javaLegacy&directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.2.3
MongoParseError: option uuidrepresentation is not supported
```

My requirement is to execute mongo queries that involves Java Legacy UUIDs and the expect the query results to be represented like that.

I can achieve this via tools like Robo3T though.

But I am a specific case where I must do it via mongo shell.

I cannot find any support for this elsewhere.

Comment: Do your queries fail when using `mongosh` as is?  If so, could you show/explain how?

Comment: It's java driver specific option, not supported in mongo shell. See if the script from https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3153 is of any help. It's all binary on BSON level and is just how they interpret byte order converting to/from string.