# How to work with legacy UUID in mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, uuid, mongo-shell

I need to work with MongoDB databases that contain ["legacy" UUID objects](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/uuid.html#legacy-handling-of-uuid-data) - BSON binData subtype 3 (created with pymongo).

The MongoDB shell version v5.0.15 can work with both legacy and "new" UUID objects:

```
> UUID("c19f6bdf-e680-4059-8b9a-a19bb879abb3")  # BSON binData subtype 4
UUID("c19f6bdf-e680-4059-8b9a-a19bb879abb3")
> UUID("c19f6bdfe68040598b9aa19bb879abb3")      # BSON binData subtype 3
BinData(3,"wZ9r3+aAQFmLmqGbuHmrsw==")
```

But with MongoDB 6.0, the classic `mongo` shell is gone and the new `mongosh` doesn't support creating legacy UUID objects using the `UUID` constructor:

```
> UUID("c19f6bdf-e680-4059-8b9a-a19bb879abb3")
UUID("c19f6bdf-e680-4059-8b9a-a19bb879abb3")  # BSON binData subtype 4
> UUID("c19f6bdfe68040598b9aa19bb879abb3")
UUID("c19f6bdf-e680-4059-8b9a-a19bb879abb3")  # also BSON binData subtype 4
```

**Is there some way how to switch the new MongoDB 6.0 shell (`mongosh`) to use the legacy UUID by default?**

The motivation is that colleagues are used to work with the `UUID()` constructor and now could mistakenly create documents with the new UUID subtype, which could break the application logic.

I know the ideal solution in the long-term is to migrate our databases to use the new UUID objects (binData subtype 4) instead. But that will be a longer process and during the migration the situation would be even worse - some databases could use the legacy format (subtype 3) and other databases the new (subtype 4).

Comment: Honestly I think the whole topic of legacy vs. new UUID format is not really well covered in documentation and elsewhere, almost as if it is a non-problem. I would very gladly prefer to see some transparent UUID migration process offered directly by the MongoDB engine.

Comment: Similar question (unanswered): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72123383/mongosh-how-to-connect-with-uuidrepresentation-javalegacy

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple HEX -> Base64 conversion. Try this:

```
db.testbin.insertOne({
   uuid_data: BinData(3, "wZ9r3+aAQFmLmqGbuHmrsw=="),
   bin_data: Binary(Buffer.from("c19f6bdfe68040598b9aa19bb879abb3", "hex"), 3),
})

db.testbin.find({})

[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("64623984839586cbe11d6a48"),
    uuid_data: Binary(Buffer.from("c19f6bdfe68040598b9aa19bb879abb3", "hex"), 3),
     bin_data: Binary(Buffer.from("c19f6bdfe68040598b9aa19bb879abb3", "hex"), 3)
  }
]
```

See [Binary()](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/binary.html)

You can overwrite `UUID` function (maybe in `.mongoshrc.js` file):

```
function UUID(val) {
   return Binary(Buffer.from(val, "hex"), 3)
}

> UUID("c19f6bdfe68040598b9aa19bb879abb3")
Binary(Buffer.from("c19f6bdfe68040598b9aa19bb879abb3", "hex"), 3)
```

Comment: Good idea to redefine `UUID()` in `.mongoshrc.js`!